# By special relativity, a particle can only couple to an EM field?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, field-theory

By special relativity, the Lagrangian for the coupling must be

$$  u_i A^i  . $$

Here $u_i $ is the four-velocity, and $A^i$ is the four-potential.

So, a particle can only couple to an EM field? No other field?

Answer (score 1):

No, many other couplings are possible. For example, in the very simple Lagrangian
$$L = \frac{1}{2} mv^2 - mgh$$
we have coupled the particle to the gravitational field $\phi = gh$. This is already in relativistically invariant form, since both $m$ and $\phi$ are scalars. (Of course the real story for coupling to gravity is more complicated, but this works on the level of SR.)